# How do I install the updated version of Google Chrome using Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: google-chrome

I have downloaded the newest version of Google Chrome and I don't know how to install it using Ubuntu Software Center. What do I need to do to to install the new version of Google Chrome that I have downloaded?

Comment: Are you saying that google-chrome is not already updating automatically? (It should be!) Or are you saying that you don't know what to do with the deb file sitting on your desktop? Or are you saying that there is some kind of error with Software Center?  Can you please edit your question to clarify the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Then your done.